# URL Rewrite Rules in specific format

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have written a .htaccess file for URL to rewrite but it has some error due to which does't give desired output, need some expert opinion/result to get it right.

**Here is URL I want to rewrite**

`http://theyouthtalent.com/user-wall.php?User=dillagiary&Talent=T.V`

**should be rewrite to**

`http://theyouthtalent.com/T.V/dillagiary`

and my existing .htaccess file has following lines

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /user_wall\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^User=(\w+)&Talent=(\w+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^user_wall\.php$ /%2/%1? [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ user_wall.php?User=$2&Talent=$1 [L,QSA]
```

> Important point is I want to Talent value first and then username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> http://theyouthtalent.com/user-wall.php?User=dillagiary&Talent=T.V
> ```

The `Talent` query string parameter value contains a dot (`.`), but the shorthand character class `\w` (word characters) does not include a dot. So, you need to include a dot in the pattern. ie. Change the relevant `(\w+)` pattern to `([\w.]+)`.

Also, the request URL contains a hyphen (`-`), not an underscore (`_`).

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /user-wall\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^User=(\w+)&Talent=([\w.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^user_wall\.php$ /%2/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w.]+)/(\w+)/?$ user_wall.php?User=$2&Talent=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The `\w` character class by itself is equivalent to: `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

Comment: I have added dot (`.`) but it does't make any difference, I have check my htaccess file against said URL at [link](http://htaccess.mwl.be) and it says **This rule was not met**

Comment: I've just tried it using that tool you linked to and it works ok for me. (But that tool does not support the `THE_REQUEST` server variable, so you can't really test the first part with that.)

Comment: thanks @w3dk it is working now, I have mistakenly added under score (`_`) in rewrite rule while URL has hyphen (`-`) in **user-wall**

Comment: Ah yes, hadn't spotted that! :)